# Android ListView header in ListFragment crashes on back button press

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a ListFragment class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_information, container);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {
                    "See the Demo!", "Read More!" });
    header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.information_headerview, null);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.information_header_textview);
    tv.setText(Model.Information);
    getListView().addHeaderView(header);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

This works fine when I create the Fragment for the first time.  Then I when I navigate back to this fragment on back button press, in Android < 4.4 it crashes.  the logcat doesnt say anything, all I get is Thread[<1> main](Suspended(exception IllegalStateException)) and a break at documentation above public void addHeaderView(View v, Object dad, boolean isSelectable) saying:

```
/**
 * Add a fixed view to appear at the top of the list. If this method is
 * called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were
 * added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.
 * <p>
 * Note: When first introduced, this method could only be called before
 * setting the adapter with {@link #setAdapter(ListAdapter)}. Starting with
 * {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#KITKAT}, this method may be
 * called at any time. If the ListView's adapter does not extend
 * {@link HeaderViewListAdapter}, it will be wrapped with a supporting
 * instance of {@link WrapperListAdapter}.
 *
 * @param v The view to add.
 * @param data Data to associate with this view
 * @param isSelectable whether the item is selectable
 */
```

Of course, I have no problem in KitKat, but anything else crashes.

Help?

edit: logcat:

```
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add     header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.widget.ListView.addHeaderView(ListView.java:255)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at fragments.InformationFragment.onViewCreated(InformationFragment.java:53)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:842)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:697)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1431)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:453)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2121)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at com.allgoodpeopleus.evolutionp.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:82)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2099)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2575)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2329)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1806)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3327)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3300)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2460)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-09 03:46:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the answer to my question: http://code.neenbedankt.com/note-to-self-listfragment-and-header-views/

The ListView is never destroyed it seems when I navigate away.  So I have to call this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    setListAdapter(null);
}
```

to get rid of the adapter and recreate it when I press the back button.  This fits with what the documentation said about <4.4, but I didnt know how to get rid of things when I navigated away.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying it in an emulator or a real device.
I had same problem with some different sort of code and logcat was not showing relevant information and this worked for me:-
Window > Preferences > Android > Logcat > (Monitor Logcat Messages from applications in workspace) change it to VERBOSE.

Comment: it's on the emulator.  Kitkat on a real device and emulator are both fine.  i found this fine post which answers my question: http://code.neenbedankt.com/note-to-self-listfragment-and-header-views/

Comment: I think i answered the question in a way because the question included a paragraph:-                                            This works fine when I create the Fragment for the first time. Then I when I navigate back to this fr the "logcat doesnt say anything", all I get is Thread[<1> main](Suspended(exception IllegalStateException)) and a break at documentation above public void addHeaderView(View v, Object dad, boolean isSelectable)                                          My answer was to run the logcat in verbose mode and then the error will be displayed.